# How to determine from within whether a Python module/file was imported or invoked standalone?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-importlib

I would like to structure some Python code such that I can either invoke it from the command line, or import it as a package from another program.

If I import it, I will invoke it, say, through its `main()` function with some parameters.
If it's executed directly, I will call `main()` with default parameters at the end of the file.

How, from inside the module, do I determine whether to call `main()` with default parameters or not?

Alternatively, when I call `imp.importlib.import_module()` is there a way to pass options into the module (say through its globals) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a file is run directly with:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("I am run as a script!")
else:
    print("I am being imported")
```

Comment: Thanks.   Perhaps it's a different question, but it is possible at the time of (i.e. before)  import to force some globals or other values seen in the module during import?